# How to make text to the right

Tags: html, css

How do I make my text to the right of the image? Like you would on a word document.

[image: pic example]

[image: html and css code]

Comment: `text-align: right;` on the div or p should do the trick.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/9256189)

Comment: apply the display:flex property to the parent element of the div and add display:right to the fog class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have use `display:flex;` in css for  `div block`.

It will make text always right to the image.

```css
*{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

img{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:#69b6fa;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
}

div
{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Just Chill</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img src="" alt="150x150">
    <span>Your Text</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: right;` to the image and it will align right

Answer (score 0):

I think `text-align: right` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your photo in a container, and give your container a "display: flex" property like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="...">
</div>
```

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

You can set most of the element's position conveniently with this flex trick
See more in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you should use `display : flex` on a container

```css
.container {
display : flex;
align-items : flex-start;
justify-content : flex-start;
}

.container p {
margin-left : 15px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <p>I'm on the right !</p>
</div>
```